# Hiding GridView Columns on RunTime

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i am trying to hid some columns of gridView on run time by matching their HeaderText but its not working for me. here is the code i am trying

```
  protected void gridview_rowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
       {

         foreach (DataControlField col in gvRecoed.Columns)
    {
        try
        {
            if (col.HeaderText == cat_check.SelectedItem.Text.Trim())
            {
                col.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        { }
     }
   }
```

**cat_check is a CheckBoxList**

Comment: Try this...  foreach (DataControlField column in GridView1.Columns)
        if (column.HeaderText == "FirstName")
            column.Visible = false;

Comment: i already tried it by giving hard coded value but it didn't worked . . .

Comment: Ok do one thing...give a css class to that gridview control now in jquery ...$(".cssClassName").hide();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to hide the column in `RowDataBound` which is triggered for every row in the grid?

Instead you could use the `DataBound` event which is called once after the grid was databound.

```
protected void gridview_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cat_check.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string columnName =  SelectedItem.Text;
        var column = gridView1.Columns.Cast<DataControlField>()
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.HeaderText == columnName);
        if (column != null) column.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void gridview_rowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{   
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
         foreach (DataControlField col in gvSource.Columns)
          {
           try
            {
              if (col.HeaderText == cat_check.SelectedItem.Text.Trim())
               {
                 col.Visible = false;
                }
             }
            catch (Exception exe)
           { }
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: its working but only for one column , like if i select name, class and section from CheckBoxList to hide it only hides name  . . . .

Comment: i have checked it again SelectedItem names and Column names are same

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple answer.
Create css as below

.classHide{
display:none
}

then instead of col.hide,just assign classHide cssclass to the column.

 e.g. col.cssclass="classHide"

Comment: i am selecting names of columns to hide from CheckBox on run time . . .

Comment: yes it is no problem. from code behind you cannot set visible false. beacuse it didnt work. just set col.cssclass = "classhide"